# My Discord bot get error to showing servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

hello i want my discordbot show my mc server

i try this code:

> ```
> const {Client, RichEmbed } = require('discord.js')
>  
> const bot = new Client()
>  
> const ping = require('minecraft-server-util')
>  
> const token = 'tokenid'
>  
> const PREFIX = '!'
>  
> bot.on('ready', () =>{
>     console.log('Bot has come online.')
> })
>  
> bot.on('message', message =>{
> if (message.content === 'dnm') {
>
> ping('hypixel.net', 25565, (error, reponse) =>{
>     if(error) throw error
>     const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
>     .setTitle('Sunucu Bilgileri')
>     .addField('Sunucu ip', reponse.host)
>     .addField('Sunucu Versiyonu', reponse.version)
>     .addField('online oyuncu', reponse.onlinePlayers)
>     .addField('Maksimun Oyuncu', reponse.maxPlayers)
>
>     message.channel.send(Embed)
> ```

```
    })
}
```

> ```
>     }
>  
> })
>  
> bot.login(token)
> ```

but i get this error

**

> (node:13980) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: RichEmbed is
> not a constructor`enter code here`
> at D:\Discordbot\MCBOT\bas.js:27:31
> at D:\Discordbot\MCBOT\node_modules\minecraft-server-util\src\index.js:137:23
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) (node:13980)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
> rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1) (node:13980) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code.

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Discord.js v12, `RichEmbed` was removed in favor of `MessageEmbed`. Pretty much all you've got to do is replace `RichEmbed` with `MessageEmbed` everywhere in your code, like I have done so below:

```js
const {Client, MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js')
 
const bot = new Client()
 
const ping = require('minecraft-server-util')
 
const token = 'tokenid'
 
const PREFIX = '!'
 
bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Bot has come online.')
})
 
bot.on('message', message =>{
 
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ')
 
    switch(args[0]){
        case 'mc':
 
            if(!args[1]) return message.channel.send('You must type a minecraft server ip')
            if(!args[2]) return message.channel.send('You must type a minecraft server port')
 
            ping(args[1], parseInt(args[2]), (error, reponse) =>{
                if(error) throw error
                const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Server Status')
                .addField('Server IP', reponse.host)
                .addField('Server Version', reponse.version)
                .addField('Online Players', reponse.onlinePlayers)
                .addField('Max Players', reponse.maxPlayers)
               
                message.channel.send(Embed)
            })
        break;
    }
})
 
bot.login(token)
```

I hope this helps!